# IIS impede de carregar alguns javascript e estilo

Tags: javascript, html, iis

Tenho uma página HTML que eu estou fazendo alguns testes. Sem o IIS, funciona normalmente, porem quando eu chamo pelo IIS, aí começa os problemas:

1) O Estilo geral sobe (`viewer.css`), porem quando eu coloco um estilo num elemento, como botão(`style="display: none;`), aí não funciona, ou seja, o botão continua sendo visualizado, mesmo com `display: none`, o que não acontece fora do IIS.
2) Funções javascript também não sobe, tenho uma função que carrega um documento PDF e nada. Coloquei vários `alert()` exatamente onde é carregado e nenhum `alert()` subiu.

O IIS pode matar tanto javascript quanto CSS? Como eu resolvo isso? É uma página HTML pura, não é Asp.net.

Abaixo o html da página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright 2012 Mozilla Foundation

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.

Adobe CMap resources are covered by their own copyright but the same license:

    Copyright 1990-2015 Adobe Systems Incorporated.

See https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/cmap-resources
-->
<html dir="ltr" mozdisallowselectionprint moznomarginboxes>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
    <title>PDF.js viewer</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="viewer.css"/>

    <script src="compatibility.js"></script>



<!-- This snippet is used in production (included from viewer.html) -->
<link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="locale/locale.properties"/>
<script src="l10n.js"></script>
<script src="pdf.js"></script>



    <script src="debugger.js"></script>
    <script src="viewer.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body tabindex="1" class="loadingInProgress">
    <div id="outerContainer">

      <div id="sidebarContainer">
        <div id="toolbarSidebar">
          <div class="splitToolbarButton toggled">
            <button id="viewThumbnail" class="toolbarButton group toggled" title="Show Thumbnails" tabindex="2" data-l10n-id="thumbs">
               <span data-l10n-id="thumbs_label">Thumbnails</span>
            </button>
            <button id="viewOutline" class="toolbarButton group" title="Show Document Outline" tabindex="3" data-l10n-id="outline">
               <span data-l10n-id="outline_label">Document Outline</span>
            </button>
            <button id="viewAttachments" class="toolbarButton group" title="Show Attachments" tabindex="4" data-l10n-id="attachments">
               <span data-l10n-id="attachments_label">Attachments</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebarContent">
          <div id="thumbnailView">
          </div>
          <div id="outlineView" class="hidden">
          </div>
          <div id="attachmentsView" class="hidden">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- sidebarContainer -->

      <div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="findbar hidden doorHanger hiddenSmallView" id="findbar">
          <label for="findInput" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_label">Find:</label>
          <input id="findInput" class="toolbarField" tabindex="91">
          <div class="splitToolbarButton">
            <button class="toolbarButton findPrevious" title="" id="findPrevious" tabindex="92" data-l10n-id="find_previous">
              <span data-l10n-id="find_previous_label">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
            <button class="toolbarButton findNext" title="" id="findNext" tabindex="93" data-l10n-id="find_next">
              <span data-l10n-id="find_next_label">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarField" tabindex="94">
          <label for="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_highlight">Highlight all</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="findMatchCase" class="toolbarField" tabindex="95">
          <label for="findMatchCase" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_match_case_label">Match case</label>
          <span id="findMsg" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
        </div>  <!-- findbar -->

        <div id="secondaryToolbar" class="secondaryToolbar hidden doorHangerRight">
          <div id="secondaryToolbarButtonContainer">
            <button id="secondaryPresentationMode" style="display: none;" class="secondaryToolbarButton presentationMode visibleLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="51" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
              <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
            </button>

              <button id="secondaryOpenFile" style="display: none;" class="secondaryToolbarButton openFile visibleLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="52" data-l10n-id="open_file">
                  <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
              </button>

              <button id="secondaryPrint" style="display: none;" class="secondaryToolbarButton print visibleMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="53" data-l10n-id="print">
                  <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
              </button>

            <button id="secondaryDownload" class="secondaryToolbarButton download visibleMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="54" data-l10n-id="download">
              <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
            </button>

            <a href="#" id="secondaryViewBookmark" class="secondaryToolbarButton bookmark visibleSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="55" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
              <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
            </a>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator visibleLargeView"></div>

            <button id="firstPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton firstPage" title="Go to First Page" tabindex="56" data-l10n-id="first_page">
              <span data-l10n-id="first_page_label">Go to First Page</span>
            </button>
            <button id="lastPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton lastPage" title="Go to Last Page" tabindex="57" data-l10n-id="last_page">
              <span data-l10n-id="last_page_label">Go to Last Page</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="pageRotateCw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCw" title="Rotate Clockwise" tabindex="58" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw">
              <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw_label">Rotate Clockwise</span>
            </button>
            <button id="pageRotateCcw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCcw" title="Rotate Counterclockwise" tabindex="59" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw">
              <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw_label">Rotate Counterclockwise</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="toggleHandTool" class="secondaryToolbarButton handTool" title="Enable hand tool" tabindex="60" data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable">
              <span data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable_label">Enable hand tool</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="documentProperties" class="secondaryToolbarButton documentProperties" title="Document Properties…" tabindex="61" data-l10n-id="document_properties">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_label">Document Properties…</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>  <!-- secondaryToolbar -->

        <div class="toolbar">
          <div id="toolbarContainer">
            <div id="toolbarViewer">
              <div id="toolbarViewerLeft">
                <button id="sidebarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Toggle Sidebar" tabindex="11" data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar">
                  <span data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar_label">Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <div class="toolbarButtonSpacer"></div>
                <button id="viewFind" class="toolbarButton group hiddenSmallView" title="Find in Document" tabindex="12" data-l10n-id="findbar">
                   <span data-l10n-id="findbar_label">Find</span>
                </button>
                <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                  <button class="toolbarButton pageUp" title="Previous Page" id="previous" tabindex="13" data-l10n-id="previous">
                    <span data-l10n-id="previous_label">Previous</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                  <button class="toolbarButton pageDown" title="Next Page" id="next" tabindex="14" data-l10n-id="next">
                    <span data-l10n-id="next_label">Next</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <label id="pageNumberLabel" class="toolbarLabel" for="pageNumber" data-l10n-id="page_label">Page: </label>
                <input type="number" id="pageNumber" class="toolbarField pageNumber" value="1" size="4" min="1" tabindex="15">
                <span id="numPages" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
              </div>
              <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
                <button id="presentationMode" class="toolbarButton presentationMode hiddenLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="31" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
                  <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
                </button>

                <button id="openFile" class="toolbarButton openFile hiddenLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="32" data-l10n-id="open_file">
                  <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
                </button>

                <button id="print" class="toolbarButton print hiddenMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="33" data-l10n-id="print">
                  <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
                </button>

                <button id="download" class="toolbarButton download hiddenMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="34" data-l10n-id="download">
                  <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" id="viewBookmark" class="toolbarButton bookmark hiddenSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="35" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
                  <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
                </a>

                <div class="verticalToolbarSeparator hiddenSmallView"></div>

                <button id="secondaryToolbarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Tools" tabindex="36" data-l10n-id="tools">
                  <span data-l10n-id="tools_label">Tools</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="outerCenter">
                <div class="innerCenter" id="toolbarViewerMiddle">
                  <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                    <button id="zoomOut" class="toolbarButton zoomOut" title="Zoom Out" tabindex="21" data-l10n-id="zoom_out">
                      <span data-l10n-id="zoom_out_label">Zoom Out</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                    <button id="zoomIn" class="toolbarButton zoomIn" title="Zoom In" tabindex="22" data-l10n-id="zoom_in">
                      <span data-l10n-id="zoom_in_label">Zoom In</span>
                     </button>
                  </div>
                  <span id="scaleSelectContainer" class="dropdownToolbarButton">
                     <select id="scaleSelect" title="Zoom" tabindex="23" data-l10n-id="zoom">
                      <option id="pageAutoOption" title="" value="auto" selected="selected" data-l10n-id="page_scale_auto">Automatic Zoom</option>
                      <option id="pageActualOption" title="" value="page-actual" data-l10n-id="page_scale_actual">Actual Size</option>
                      <option id="pageFitOption" title="" value="page-fit" data-l10n-id="page_scale_fit">Fit Page</option>
                      <option id="pageWidthOption" title="" value="page-width" data-l10n-id="page_scale_width">Full Width</option>
                      <option id="customScaleOption" title="" value="custom"></option>
                      <option title="" value="0.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 50 }'>50%</option>
                      <option title="" value="0.75" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 75 }'>75%</option>
                      <option title="" value="1" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 100 }'>100%</option>
                      <option title="" value="1.25" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 125 }'>125%</option>
                      <option title="" value="1.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 150 }'>150%</option>
                      <option title="" value="2" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 200 }'>200%</option>
                      <option title="" value="3" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 300 }'>300%</option>
                      <option title="" value="4" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 400 }'>400%</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="loadingBar">
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="glimmer">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <menu type="context" id="viewerContextMenu">
          <menuitem id="contextFirstPage" label="First Page"
                    data-l10n-id="first_page"></menuitem>
          <menuitem id="contextLastPage" label="Last Page"
                    data-l10n-id="last_page"></menuitem>
          <menuitem id="contextPageRotateCw" label="Rotate Clockwise"
                    data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw"></menuitem>
          <menuitem id="contextPageRotateCcw" label="Rotate Counter-Clockwise"
                    data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw"></menuitem>
        </menu>

        <div id="viewerContainer" tabindex="0">
          <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="errorWrapper" hidden='true'>
          <div id="errorMessageLeft">
            <span id="errorMessage"></span>
            <button id="errorShowMore" data-l10n-id="error_more_info">
              More Information
            </button>
            <button id="errorShowLess" data-l10n-id="error_less_info" hidden='true'>
              Less Information
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="errorMessageRight">
            <button id="errorClose" data-l10n-id="error_close">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth"></div>
          <textarea id="errorMoreInfo" hidden='true' readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- mainContainer -->

      <div id="overlayContainer" class="hidden">
        <div id="passwordOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <p id="passwordText" data-l10n-id="password_label">Enter the password to open this PDF file:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <input type="password" id="password" class="toolbarField" />
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="passwordCancel" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_cancel">Cancel</span></button>
              <button id="passwordSubmit" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_ok">OK</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="documentPropertiesOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_name">File name:</span> <p id="fileNameField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_size">File size:</span> <p id="fileSizeField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_title">Title:</span> <p id="titleField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_author">Author:</span> <p id="authorField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_subject">Subject:</span> <p id="subjectField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_keywords">Keywords:</span> <p id="keywordsField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creation_date">Creation Date:</span> <p id="creationDateField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_modification_date">Modification Date:</span> <p id="modificationDateField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creator">Creator:</span> <p id="creatorField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_producer">PDF Producer:</span> <p id="producerField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_version">PDF Version:</span> <p id="versionField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_page_count">Page Count:</span> <p id="pageCountField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="documentPropertiesClose" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="document_properties_close">Close</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- overlayContainer -->

    </div> <!-- outerContainer -->
    <div id="printContainer"></div>
<div id="mozPrintCallback-shim" hidden>
  <style>
@media print {
  #printContainer div {
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
  </style>
  <style scoped>
#mozPrintCallback-shim {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999;

  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#mozPrintCallback-shim[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  #mozPrintCallback-shim {
    display: none;
  }
}

#mozPrintCallback-shim .mozPrintCallback-dialog-box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -50px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 400px;

  padding: 9px;

  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  background-color: #474747;

  color: hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
#mozPrintCallback-shim .progress-row {
  clear: both;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
#mozPrintCallback-shim progress {
  width: 100%;
}
#mozPrintCallback-shim .relative-progress {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}
#mozPrintCallback-shim .progress-actions {
  clear: both;
}
  </style>
  <div class="mozPrintCallback-dialog-box">
    <!-- TODO: Localise the following strings -->
    Preparing document for printing...
    <div class="progress-row">
      <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
      <span class="relative-progress">0%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-actions">
      <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="mozPrintCallback-cancel">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito provavelmente o `IIS` nao consegue encontrar os ficheiros `.js` e `.css` (muito provavelmente devido aos caminhos). Quando não usa o `IIS`, usa o que? `IISExpress`? Tente explicar melhor quais as diferenças entre um ambiente e o outro. Se abrir a consola do seu *browser* vê algum pedido para os arquivos que deviam ser carregados?

Comment: @Omni, ok, não uso o express. É apenas um html simples, que quando eu não utilizo o IIS eu starto a página a partir da pasta onde ela se encontra. Não uso Visual Studio nesse "projetinho".

Comment: Muito provavelmente o `IIS` não consegue carregar os caminhos entao. Inclua os seus scripts assim  `<script src="~/myscripts.js"></script> `. Mais [alguma leitura](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574119/relative-paths-in-iis-7-web-applications-under-a-website) sobre caminhos no `IIS`.

Comment: @Omni, o estilo sobe, não sobe o estilo em linha que eu coloquei, ou seja, em cima do elemento button(style="display: none"). Isso não está funcionando. Coloquei um alert() no começo do javascript que sobe primeiro e ontem ele não disparou e hoje já está disparando. Não sei o que aconteceu, mas continua não funcionando, mas isso eu estou analisando. só gostaria de saber se é possível o IIS inibir javascript e css(em linha), apenas isso.

Comment: @pnet Veja [se esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21718881/1242661) se aplica ao seu caso.

Comment: @Omni, não é isso. Pelas configurações do link supra passado, a minha config. está bem parecida.

Comment: Não é um problema de cache do IIS? Exprimente dar um `CTRL` + `F5` no navegador após realizar as alterações nos arquivos JS e CSS.

Comment: @alvarodms, cara já fiz tudo isso. Peguei um link do PDF.js e estou dando uma olhada nele, pois há outros problemas além destes, já abertos em outros posts. Não estou nem acreditando que seja do IIS apenas. Deve ter alguma coisa nos arquivos js que acompanham a biblioteca, que pode impedir isso, sei lá, estou apenas chutando, já não sei mais nada.

Comment: Poderia mostrar a parte do HTML que referencia os arquivos?

Comment: @Moykn, vou editar o post e postar todo o html.

Comment: Resolvi a situação. A questão é que ele possui duas declarações para os botões, ou seja, uma para caso de abrir em modo local e outra não(isso eu não sabia). Quando setei o estilo, setei o de modo local e deixei o outro e por isso não funcionou. Corrigir e agora esconde os botões. Não estava no IIS o problema, era "BIOS".